# How to access the NTFS partition where I've installed BOOT-LOADER of ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: grub2, ntfs, bootloader, 9.04

I have two HDDs>> hd0 is internal , **hd1 is external**.

I installed Ubuntu 9.04 in the external hdd as follows:
"\home" ext3-partition in (hd1,2)
**"\root" ext3-partition in (hd1,3)** 
"swap"       partition in (hd1,4)

**During installation, I changed the bootloader setting.** (I intended Ubuntu 9.04 to boot from the external hard disk itself.) I set the (hd1,0) **NTFS** partition for installing
the boot-loader. [I thought the bootloader will be installed in that NTFS partition &  its data will remain intact.

Now (hd1,0) is a partition of 800GB(!!!) & it contains **~560GB of my data which I'm unable to access** from Windows/ newly installed Ubuntu 9.04/ Ubuntu 8.10 live-disk...Windows is unable to read the data (as expected :D); Windows wants to format the disk before using!!!

Unexpectedly, Ubuntu doesn't even show the 800-GB space in "Places/Computer" although it shows the partition as of **"Unknown file system" in "GParted" (partition editor)**.

I need the data (~560GB)... pl help...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something wicked happened to that NTFS partition. My move would be to pay for Stellar Phoenix or equivalent data rescue/forensic tool. In that case, you will need that ~560gb of free space from some other drive, since those tools are for copying data - not repairing broken filesystems.

Comment: (possibly off-topic) Linux's NTFS resize included in some older Ubuntu version installers is an effective way to trash Windows versions beyond XP.

Comment: I wonder Ubuntu can't read the file system where it has installed its own bootloader!!

Comment: Can't say, what happened. A bug somewhere? I'm not endorsing software piracy, piratebay versions are illegal. But I endorse you to try out that Stellar Phoenix, I tried it years ago. It really saved my day.

Comment: Stellar Phoenix worked brilliantly!!